# Excel SaveAs changes active workbook - How to SaveAs and keep active workbook active?

Tags: vba, excel, macros

In an MS-Excel 2007 macro, I want to save the the workbook (which contains the macro) to another workbook before beginning updates. However, when I execute the SaveAs, the current workbook becomes the saved workbook and not the original one I stared with...

Say I start with workbook "A.xlsm", within workbook "A.xlsm" I issue command

```
With ActiveWorkbook
          .SaveAs FileName:=ThisWorkbook.Path + "\" & "B.xlsm"
          Close 0
End With
```

Any changes in the active workbook appears in workbook "B.xlsm" not "A.xlsm"!!!

Question
Within workbook "A.xlsm", how can I save a copy without changing the active workbook?

Comment: [Another Way](http://www.siddharthrout.com/2011/09/02/using-save-as-and-keeping-original-file-and-new-file-open-at-the-same-time/)

Comment: @SiddharthRout That post has been put 'under renovation'. Here's a Wayback Machine link to the original article while he's updating it: https://web.archive.org/web/20131213230603/http://www.siddharthrout.com/2011/09/02/using-save-as-and-keeping-original-file-and-new-file-open-at-the-same-time/

Comment: @AustinGordon [Updated Link](http://www.siddharthrout.com/index.php/2019/01/12/using-save-as-and-keeping-original-file-and-new-file-open-at-the-same-time-2/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SaveCopyAs saves a copy of the workbook without changing any references.

`ActiveWorkbook.SaveCopyAs FileName:=ActiveWorkbook.Path + "\" & "B.xlsm"`

---

```
Sub TestSaveAs()
    Dim xlWB As Workbook
    Set xlWB = ActiveWorkbook

    ActiveWorkbook.SaveCopyAs Filename:=ActiveWorkbook.Path + "\" & "B.xlsm"

    Debug.Print "ActiveWorkbook.FullName: " & ActiveWorkbook.FullName
    Debug.Print "xlWB.FullName: " & xlWB.FullName

End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: My understanding is that automatically changes the active workbook to "Thisworkbook".

Comment: @NoChance I had a typo in my answer.   I included a test to show that SaveCopyAs doesn't change any references.

Comment: Excellent point thank you. Congratulations on knowing such a difference!

Comment: Thanks for the check mark!

Comment: Well deserved. I think SaveAs in this context, is simply harmful...It is as harmful as SQL DELETE FROM TableX, which does not ask for a condition!

Answer (score 1):

Create a Workbook variable and assign `ActiveWorkbook` to it before saving

```
Dim xlWB as Workbook
Set xlWB = ActiveWorkbook
xlWB.SaveAs FileName:=ThisWorkbook.Path & "/" & "B.xlsm"
```

Then you can refer to `xlWB` instead of `ActiveWorkbook`, which always stays the same Workbook

Comment: I think this would work. I assume that I could then do xlWB.Activate to make it the active workbook again. I will test and accept this as an answer if it works. Thx.

Comment: yes you can, or just replace the `ActiveWorkbook` wherever you need it with the `xlWB`. Then you don't need to use `Activate` to access it